# Get last 15 lines from a large file in SFTP with phpseclib

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I want to get the last 15 lines from a large file (30MB) from a SFTP server using PHP.

I tried using the phpseclib's SFTP functionality like that:

```
include('./Net/SFTP.php');
$sftp = new Net_SFTP("server", 2022);
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit("Login error");
}
$size = $sftp->size('./file.txt');
$Container = nl2br($sftp->get('./file.txt', false, $size - 5000));
if( !empty($Container) ) {
    echo $Container;
} else {
    exit("empty file");
}
```

But this still loads in like 2 minutes for my large file.

Is it possible to get only the last X lines from a large file?

Comment: Look into CURL [here](https://serverfault.com/q/18834/255167) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121314/171904)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus it looks like a CURL request into SFTP is hard.
I've tried it now and the content returned is NULL.

Comment: Because you're downloading the entire file first, and PHPseclib doesn't have a facility for partial requests. Why not switch to SSH and issue `tail -n 15 file.txt`?

Comment: @Sammitch - omg. I totally forgot that i can connect to SSH because this is sftp .. i will try that now. you can post this as an answer btw

Comment: All I wrote was a suggestion. Once you write the code you can post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: it didnt work :( connection to SSH says `Server refused to allocate pty` it is a SFTP only server

Comment: Actually the non-accepted answer to the question @tim linked shows that you _can_ apparently do this with PHPseclib's SFTP. However you'll have to read it backwards in chunks until you have the last 15 lines.

Comment: @Sammitch - i see .. but i dont know how to read it **backwards** in a loop. im still a beginner in this :/

Answer (score 3):

The following should result in a blob of text with at least 15 lines from the end of the file that you can then process further with your existing logic. You may want to tweak some of the logic depending on if your file ends with a trailing newline, etc.

```
$filename = './file.txt'

$filesize = $sftp->size($filename);
$buffersize = 4096;

$offset = $filesize; // start at the end
$result = '';
$lines = 0;

while( $offset > 0 && $lines < 15 ) {
  // work backwards
  if( $offset < $buffersize ) {
    $offset = 0;
  } else {
    $offset -= $buffer_size;
  }
  $buffer = $sftp->get($filename, false, $offset, $buffer_size));
  // count the number of newlines as we go
  $lines += substr_count($buffer, "\n");
  $result = $buffer . $result;
}
```

Comment: Consider moving your very good answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/17283326/850848